# C++ : Reading File contents into wstring

Tags: c++

I am facing an issue when reading the file contents in C++.

I have a text file with content 
"Password=(|OBFUSCATED:A;Q=K?[LNQGMXNLd282>;3Cl]*I(n7$:OBFUSCATED|)".

when i try to read the file and save its content to wstring, complete file contents are not read but instead only "Password=(|OBFUSCATED:" is read into wstring variable.

Codesnippet is :

```
std::wifstream input1(path);
std::wstring content((std::istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t>(input1)),
        (std::istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t>()));
```

Need help in reading the file contents.

Thanks in Advance!!

LATHA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out on a limb, add `binary` to the open flags:

```
std::wifstream input1(path, std::ios::binary);
std::wstring content((std::istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t>(input1)),
    {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pulling info from several places... This should be the fastest and best way:

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

//Returns true if successful.
bool readInFile(std::string pathString)
{
  //Make sure the file exists and is an actual file.
  if (!std::filesystem::is_regular_file(pathString))
  {
    return false;
  }
  //Convert relative path to absolute path.
  pathString = std::filesystem::weakly_canonical(pathString);
  //Open the file for reading (binary is fastest).
  std::wifstream in(pathString, std::ios::binary);
  //Make sure the file opened.
  if (!in)
  {
    return false;
  }
  //Wide string to store the file's contents.
  std::wstring fileContents;
  //Jump to the end of the file to determine the file size.
  in.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
  //Resize the wide string to be able to fit the entire file (Note: Do not use reserve()!).
  fileContents.resize(in.tellg());
  //Go back to the beginning of the file to start reading.
  in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
  //Read the entire file's contents into the wide string.
  in.read(fileContents.data(), fileContents.size());
  //Close the file.
  in.close();
  //Do whatever you want with the file contents.
  std::wcout << fileContents << L" " << fileContents.size();
  return true;
}
```